# Spring MVC: Displaying of validation messages after redirect

Tags: redirect, spring-mvc

I have some very strange problem with displaying of error messages after redirect. I use RedirectAttributes to pass BindingResult object with error messages to a view, but this solution doesn't work.

When I return just a view name withou redirect, everything works fine.

Can someone give an advice, but without session usage?

```
@Controller
public class UserRegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/registration", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView registrationPage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("user-registration/registration-form");
        modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/registration", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView registerUser(@ModelAttribute @Valid User user, 
            BindingResult result,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:registration.html");

        User tempUser = userService.get(user.getEmail());
        Map<String, String> messages = new HashMap<String, String>();

        if (tempUser == null && ! result.hasErrors()) {
            userService.save(user);
            messages.put("success", "message.user.success.register");
        } else {
            messages.put("error", "message.user.invalid.register");
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("user", user);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errors", result);
        }

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messages", messages);

        return modelAndView;

    }

}
```

And the view code:

```
<p>

    <c:forEach var="message" items="${messages}">
        <span class="${message.key}"><spring:message code="${message.value}" /></span><br />
    </c:forEach>

</p>

<form:form method="POST" commandName="user" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/registration.html">
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><spring:message code="user.registration.email" /></td>
        <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
        <td><form:errors cssClass="error" path="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><spring:message code="user.registration.password" /></td>
        <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
        <td><form:errors cssClass="error" path="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

There should really be no reason to redirect while there are errors remain on the same page and only on success redirect. The reason for redirecting has to do with ensuring the browser does not attempt to repeat the same form submission when the back button is used, but while input is invalid the simplest thing to do is remain on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to look at this:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8968

And try returning a String rather than a ModelAndView

Comment: Another idea, maybe since you're setting the ModelAndView to a new object in the GET mapping, that overwrites the redirect flash variables you've passed in?

Maybe pass in the model and see if the redirect flash variables are present:

'public ModelAndView registrationPage(Model model) {
    ....'

Comment: Regarding the link to jira: I use 3.2.3 version of Spring